# IR camera stream

Tags: kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,
I wanna get the IR camera stream from the kinect but I get black screen when I launch this command:

```
rosrun image_view image_view image:=camera/ir/image_raw
```

PS: All the other topics work fine.
I don't really know what's going wrong ?

---

I'm working with ROS-Hydro in ubuntu 12.04 64bit.

Thank y'all

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/174586/ir-camera-stream/) by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on ROS Answers with karma: 751 on 2014-06-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> rosrun image_view image_view image:=/camera/ir/image  _image_transport:=theora

---

Originally posted by [Sanjayan_Ravi](https://answers.ros.org/users/19002/sanjayan_ravi/) with karma: 16 on 2014-06-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on 2014-06-25**:
Thank you.
Have you test it ?
It works for you ?

**Comment by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on 2014-06-26**:
It doesn't work for me

**Comment by [Sanjayan_Ravi](https://answers.ros.org/users/19002/sanjayan_ravi/) on 2014-06-26**:
well i am using a asus xtion live pro camera, i dont use kinect but still it should work generally. may be use "rostopic list" command and check the topic once agin

**Comment by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on 2014-06-27**:
OK it works now even it works like "flashing" but I'll try to look for a solution
my question is:
"_image_transport:=theora"
what that is mean ?

**Comment by [Sanjayan_Ravi](https://answers.ros.org/users/19002/sanjayan_ravi/) on 2014-06-27**:
theora is compression algorithm, _image_transport:=theora means that i am requesting the output to be in compressed format.

**Comment by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on 2014-06-27**:
OK yes.
Now I'm trying to do that using a node so as to do some image processing after ?
did you do that before ?

**Comment by [Sanjayan_Ravi](https://answers.ros.org/users/19002/sanjayan_ravi/) on 2014-06-27**:
no actually i am very new to this.

**Comment by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on 2014-06-27**:
Me too :D
anyway Thank you